# How do you display a custom single wp template based on the referring category?

Tags: wordpress, templates

When a post is cross-indexed, how do you control which custom (category-based) template wordpress displays? It seems uncontrollable at first glance, but I'm sure there's a way.

Do you put paramaters into the query that generates the link to the post, or wha?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to display a certain template for a specific category, Wordpress has you covered. Simply make a template with the name 'category-%slug%.php', stick it in your theme directory, and when you view that category, you'll see the template that you created.

[More Info on Wordpress Template Heirarchies](http://codex.wordpress.org/images/1/18/Template_Hierarchy.png)